# Google Analytics goal not capturing all events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

I have a goal setup to capture all pages containing a specific url, for example:

"www.site.com/thank-you/?purchaseID=xxxxxxx&transactionID=xxxx"

I want to make sure that "?" is defined in the goal, as no direct visits are counted.

For some reason, my goals are either not working at all, or missing some goal completions (as I am seeing these pages visited elsewhere in Google Analytics).

Currently, I have this as a "Begins with" statement: ^/thank-you/?

I've also tried a "Regular Expressions" with: ^www.siteurl.com/thank-you/?*

None of these seem to be working the way that I am wanting them to though. Any advance is appreciated.

Comment: params should be "www.site.com/thank-you/?purchaseID=xxxxxxx&transactionID=xxxx"

Answer (score 0):

The character **?** is a functional command in the regex so you should use the escape character "\" before it to have it considered as a string. Try this:

```
^\/thank-you\/\?
```